# Display objects from json file

Tags: arrays, json

Please show me how to map and access the data. I need to print out a list of all "url"
[This is how the json looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dMhM0.png)

```
  return pressReleases ? (
<Main>
  {pressReleases.map((item) => (
    <TextCell key={item.news_id}>
      <CategoryText>
        {item.content.attachments.url}
      </CategoryText>
    </TextCell>
  ))}
  ;
</Main>
```

) : null;
};

Comment: attachments is an array. you need to loop attachments to get the URL. `item.content.attachments.map(attachment => attachment.url)`.
Note: this will return more than one URL's if more than objects are found in the attachments array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Attachment is an array of objects and each object has the key call `url` which is what you want to retrieve and print it out. In order to do that you need to iterate over the attachments array.

```
...
...
<CategoryText>
   {item.content.attachments.map(attachment => (
      <p>{attachment.url}</p>
   )}
</CategoryText>
...
...
```